# First Cell Static Button - UICollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cell

I would like the first cell in my UICollectionView to always exist and become a button. I know how to check for the button when tapped (just be checking the indexPath.row == 0).

So how do I actually add the first cell as a one-time static object? Similar to how the Pages iOS app works?

I know one way, where you could just adjust the content/hide etc on a normal cell if index is 0 - however there must be a better way

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up two prototype cells:  one for just the first cell (with a reuseIdentifier such as `FirstCell`) and one for the rest of the cells (with a reuse identifier such as `MainCells`).  Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` choose the reuseIdentifier based upon the `indexPath.item`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

    var reuseIdentifier = (indexPath.item == 0) ? "FirstCell" : "MainCells"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

**Update**: (moved from comment)

Note that to keep from just replacing your first cell, you have to increase your count in `numberOfItemsInSection` by 1 to account for the extra cell, and then subtract 1 from `indexPath.item` when you are populating your main cells.

Comment: Thanks, so i just need to add the cell manually? How would i do this?  Sorry if i don't understand

Comment: Thanks, although doing it this way will now overwrite my first MainCell with the FirstCell. e.g. instead of: 1 FirstCell and 6 MainCell, I get: 1 FirstCell and 5 MainCell